# Inverse function

Tags: functions

What probably could be the inverse of following function?

```
y = (x^(1/t)-a^(1/t))*(x^(1/t)-c*b^(1/t))/(x^(1/t)-a^(1/t))*(x^(1/t)-c*b^(1/t))+
      (x^(1/t)-   b^(1/t))*x^(1/t)-c*a^(1/t)
```

a,b,c & t are the parameters.
Any help is going to be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please, refer to the help section in order to improve the fomatting of your future answers/questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Solve` on an equation (`==` instead of `=`).  It is essentially a quadratic equation, so there are two solutions.  Either there is no inverse or there are two, depending whether you restrict the domain appropriately.

```
eqn = y == (x^(1/t) - a^(1/t))*(x^(1/t) - c*b^(1/t))/(x^(1/t) - a^(1/t))*(x^(1/t) - 
      c*b^(1/t)) + (x^(1/t) - b^(1/t))*x^(1/t) - c*a^(1/t);
soln = Solve[eqn, x]

(* {{x -> 4^-t (-b^((1/t)) (-1 - 2 c) -
           Sqrt[b^(2/t) + 8 a^(1/t) c + 4 b^(2/t) c - 4 b^(2/t) c^2 + 8 y])^t},
   {x -> 4^-t (-b^((1/t)) (-1 - 2 c) +
           Sqrt[b^(2/t) + 8 a^(1/t) c + 4 b^(2/t) c - 4 b^(2/t) c^2 + 8 y])^t}} *)
```

Check both solutions:

```
eqn /. soln // PowerExpand // Expand
(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Really grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

Inverse of a function is calculated using `InverseFunction`. So converting your equation to some function,

```
g[a_] = (x^(1/t) - 
     a^(1/t))*(x^(1/t) - c*b^(1/t))/(x^(1/t) - a^(1/t))*(x^(1/t) - 
     c*b^(1/t)) + (x^(1/t) - b^(1/t))*x^(1/t) - c*a^(1/t)

gft = InverseFunction[g]
```

Now checking it,

```
gft[4]
```

gives (*$\left(\frac{c^2 b^{2/t}-2 c b^{1/t} x^{1/t}-b^{1/t} x^{1/t}+2  x^{2/t}-4}{c}\right)^t$*) which is probably the inverse function of your function. Repeat this with simple equation (say x^2), you shall get result as -Sqrt[2] for 4 as inverse.